# Find a whole sentence by SQL Contains command

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, filetable

Search for a whole sentence in a file stored in file table using `CONTAINS`command ?

For example if user enter "SQL Server" sentence I want to search for files that just contain exactly "SQL Server" not "SQL SOME TEXT Server"

I get the following error : **Syntax error near 'Server' in the full-text search condition 'SQL Server'**

```
select * 
from files 
where contains(file_stream,'SQL Server')
```

Then I try this one :

```
select * 
from files 
where contains(file_stream,'SQL AND Server')
```

But this returned files containing "SQL SOME TEXT Server" too.

How do I correct this?

Comment: instead use `select * from files where file_stream LIKE 'SQL AND Server'`

Comment: @TamilSelvan LIKE != Contains

Comment: @Woot4Moo , I think you are right

Comment: loads of examples in the documentation: **[IN MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187787(v=sql.90).aspx)**

Comment: @whytheq , Did you think by your self where I found out the second solution ?! You think its the reason fro down vote ?!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you want this:

```
select * from files where contains(file_stream,'"SQL Server"')
```

notice the double quote.

Comment: But what difference this double quotes make. What does '"SQL Server"'mean ?

Comment: @Vivek it does an EXACT match on the string SQL Server.  What generally happens is you need to tokenize the string parts if you don't want to use the double quotes.  It is equivalent to 'SQL' AND 'SERVER'

Comment: @Vivek i should have prefaced that with " it is my understanding that"